Why isn't Tefillin stressed more spiritually than physically
The Torah says in Deuteronomy 6:8 "וּקְשַׁרְתָּ֥ם לְא֖וֹת עַל־יָדֶ֑ךָ וְהָי֥וּ לְטֹטָפֹ֖ת בֵּ֥ין עֵינֶֽיךָ׃
" but why is the main emphasis in our culture nowadays about the physical Tefillin? The main purpose is what it was made to do, which was to be a physical "sign" so that our spiritual elements can get the aid they need to have the correct notions. As it clearly says in Exodus 13:9 "וְהָיָה֩ לְךָ֨ לְא֜וֹת עַל־יָדְךָ֗ וּלְזִכָּרוֹן֙ בֵּ֣ין עֵינֶ֔יךָ לְמַ֗עַן תִּהְיֶ֛ה תּוֹרַ֥ת יְהֹוָ֖ה בְּפִ֑יךָ כִּ֚י בְּיָ֣ד חֲזָקָ֔ה הוֹצִֽאֲךָ֥ יְהֹוָ֖ה מִמִּצְרָֽיִם׃
" that the reason to have the sign (for distinction) and the remembrance is so that (למען) we have Hashem's Torah in our mouth. These physical signs are there to help our spiritual side, because it's hard to remember sometimes what our heart should be doing, and a physical sign will assist many, especially the layman who is not so experienced in controlling his heart.
This idea seems to be strengthened by a couple of points, one of them being what's written in Proverbs 3:3 "חֶ֥סֶד וֶאֱמֶ֗ת אַֽל־יַעַ֫זְבֻ֥ךָ קָשְׁרֵ֥ם עַל־גַּרְגְּרוֹתֶ֑יךָ כָּ֝תְבֵ֗ם עַל־ל֥וּחַ לִבֶּֽךָ
" which clearly shows that these elements should be bound and written metaphorically and not physically; this adds to my point of what is of higher emphasis, the physical or spiritual (in the heart). If one just goes through the physical motions without the heart actually engaging, then what value do they provide to the person other than their development of devotion? Whereas if they devote themselves but also understand why the sign is there, then they develop their devotion and their heart so that their heart chooses to connect to Hashem instead of choosing to connect to those thoughts of vanity while wearing his Tefillin. This will also help the person continue to do it their whole life because they understand the value of it and the detriment if they don't do it.
This point has some connection to what the Rambam said in Guide for the Perplexed Part 1 Chapter 50 "דע, אתה המעיין בחיבורי זה, שההַאֲמָנָה אינה העניין הנאמר, אלא העניין המצטייר (נתפס, מומשג) בנפש, אם משתכנעים לגביו שהוא כך כפי שהצטייר.
"
And Deuteronomy 30:14 "כִּֽי־קָר֥וֹב אֵלֶ֛יךָ הַדָּבָ֖ר מְאֹ֑ד בְּפִ֥יךָ וּבִֽלְבָבְךָ֖ לַעֲשֹׂתֽוֹ
"
To summarize the question: Why isn't the main priority and emphasis regarding Tefillin on the spiritual side (in the heart and mouth) rather than just the motions of the Tefillin; there seems to be more benefit that way. I am not saying not to wear Tefillin.
I very much appreciate the work you guys do on this site.

Who said it's not stressed spiritually too? I don't understand why you are trying to prioritize one over the other. It's not a zero-sum game

The question is not constructive. The OP's question has many proofs why spiritual aspects of tefilin are important, but there are no concrete examples what it should mean.

@YDJ Are you asking what are some examples where a sign on the hand and a remembrance between the eyes can assist a jew with Hashem's commandments? If there is a sign constantly on someone's hand to not steal then there's a higher chance that when he's about to steal he will see the sign and not steal. There are many examples, here's another if someone sees that his friend needs help offloading a donkey he will surely help him when there is a sign between his eyes to remind him. Like the quote from Proverbs, that chesed and emet should be bound so that they are qualities always chosen.

@DoubleAA more benefit.

@Shamir I don't understand your response to me. What is "more benefit"?

@Shamir Please suggest a reference or bring examples. However, that's non-normative mussar, like Madregas haAdam or Przysucha chassidut.

Who says we “emphasize the spiritual” part of Teffilin? The fact that the physical part is also important, does not detract from its spiritual purpose. If anyone’s told you otherwise, you’re learning from the wrong person.

If you are making a critique about people who perform mitzvos in a perfunctory way, then indeed, people are supposed to wear their tefillin while pondering and appreciating their duty to observe the Torah, etc. As Rabbeinu Avraham ben HaRambam discusses at length in HaMaspik L'Ovdei HaShem, when the Torah provides an explanation for a mitzva (such as that Shabbos is a memorial to Creation and the exodus), people should keep that in mind when performing the mitzva. On the other hand, it would be incorrect and unsupported by your sources to diminish the physical component of the mitzva.

There are something like 1000 individual instructions in how to wear tefillin properly, physically and spiritually, from Moshe Rabbeinu. Before it can be a sign of anything we need to make sure all those are in place. Can you explain in the question exactly how it is possible to to stress any of these instructions any less than we currently are, so it doesn't feel like over-emphasises anything and is more balanced?

The Shulchan Aruch says clearly one should have the proper intent when wearing tefillin.
